# error while Identify the coherence value from LDA model

Tags: python, gensim, lda

I try to run the LDA model n pass LDA object to the get_coherence() it showing the error

```
x.get_coherence()
```

*** TypeError: diags() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)

My code :-

```
iModel = models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, 
num_topics=i, passes=10)

ldalist.append(iModel)

x = CoherenceModel(model=iModel, texts=tokenizedTexts, dictionary=dictionary, 
coherence=coherence)

cohValue = x.get_coherence()
```

Answer (score 3):

u_mass coherence can be calculated without the raw texts.

The texts is just the "un-vectorized" corpus.

You transform the corpus into the list of lists of words like this before you can use it for coherence:

```
texts = [[dictionary[word_id] for word_id, freq in doc] for doc in corpus]
```

Then build coherence models and get result:

```
u_mass = models.CoherenceModel(model=topic_model, corpus=corpus, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='u_mass')
u_mass_coh = u_mass.get_coherence()

c_v = models.CoherenceModel(model=topic_model, texts=texts, corpus=corpus, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_v')
c_v_coh = c_v.get_coherence()

c_uci = models.CoherenceModel(model=topic_model, texts=texts, corpus=corpus, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_uci')
c_uci_coh = c_uci.get_coherence()

c_npmi = models.CoherenceModel(model=topic_model, texts=texts, corpus=corpus, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_npmi')
c_npmi_coh = c_npmi.get_coherence()
```

Comment: texts = [[dictionary[word_id] for word_id, freq in doc] for doc in corpus]
texts
[[u'mini', u'major', u'inflammatory', u'review', u'bowl', u'disease', u'involve', u'virulence', u'aiec', u'the'], [u'interaction', u'patient', u'herb', u'ibd', u'drug', u'elderly', u'grow', u'concern']]

topic_model, texts=texts, corpus=corpus, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_v').get_coherence()

*** TypeError: diags() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)

Answer (score -2):

You can put your codes in the main() function,then use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

This works for me.